# SSRS - action dynamic between two tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report (SSRS) with two tables and two data sets, first table(tablix) to load grouped data and second table(tablix) to load detailed data.

I would like to click dynamically, when I click on the first table of a record, it shows only the details of that record selected in the second table, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to show two tables on screen at once and refresh only the second one when an item is clicked in the first table then no, you can't do this natively in SSRS.

There are two ways of doing something similar.

1. Combine both sets of data and have a single table with grouped rows. Hide the details until the group is expanded by setting the row visibility of the detail row to be based on a textbox that belongs in the parent group.
2. Use two report, have an action ("Go to Report") on the first report that launches the detail report and passes in the parameter in to filter only on the selected item.

None of these will give you exactly what you want, hopefully one of them might be an acceptable alternative.